# Qual a melhor forma de fazer Login no aplicativo via facebook e login em um servidor rest(spring boot)?

Tags: spring-boot, react-native

Estou criando um app com react native onde faço login no facebook e também tenho informações deste usuário, criadas após o login, em um servidor rest que desenvolvi com spring boot.

Como no servidor rest não vai ter senha porque o usuário já fez o login pelo facebook, qual a melhor forma de autenticar as chamadas no servidor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você integra a autenticação da sua aplicação com o Facebook, e a sua aplicação não é uma app específica para o Facebook, então você utiliza o protocolo OAuth.

Existe muito o que se falar e estudar sobre esse protocolo, mas por enquanto você precisa saber apenas o seguinte: ao se autenticar no Facebook - ou no Google, Microsoft, Yahoo! etc. - o usuário obtém um token de acesso para a aplicação que solicitou a autenticação. Esse token é informado pela aplicação cliente ao servidor. O token é válido por tempo determinado e apenas para a aplicação que pediu a autenticação.

O fluxo do Oauth parece com isso ([retirado desta página](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2)):

[image: Fluxo do OAuth]

Portanto, em ordem:

**1 -** Aplicação pede ao usuário que se autentique em um provedor de identidade (neste caso, Facebook);
**2 -** Usuário diz "Meu corpo, meu corpo está pronto. Me redirecione!";

Entre o passo 2 e o passo 3 aparece aquela tela de autenticação do Caralivro. Em algum momento aqui o usuário estará autenticado no Face.

**3 -** O resultado do passo 2 é que a aplicação recebe um token. Sua aplicação agora informa esse token para o Facebook;
**4 -** O Facebook confirma que o token que ele recebeu é o mesmo que ele deu para o usuário. A partir daqui você pode considerar o usuário autenticado pra valer.

Se a sua aplicação é web, servida via HTTP, você pode ignorar os passos 5 e 6. Caso contrário, considere que que o servidor de recursos é o seu servidor HTTP, e *Application* no diagrama é uma aplicação *desktop* ou *mobile*.

De posse disso, basta verificar se as requisições do usuário vêm com o token correto. Outras medidas de segurança podem ser usadas, como garantir que os tokens tem vida curta, validar que um token vem sempre do mesmo IP dentro de seu tempo de vida etc. Mas isso são assuntos para outras perguntas.

Comment: Perfeito, pelo serviço do facebook eu consigo verificar o token. https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx